# Change global variable from Sass mixin

Tags: scope, sass, variable-declaration

**Or why a global variable do not change on a mixin scope when passed by @content directive ?**

I'm defining $color variable as global, and its value has been set inside a mixin. When I call this mixin, I want to have $color as it's mixin value, but, passing the variable by @content directive, I always get the global value:

```
$color: #000 !default;

@mixin generate-fruits() {
    @each $fruit, $fruit-color in $fruits {
        $color: $fruit-color;
        .#{$fruit}{
            @content;

            //  Awaited result
            // background: $color;
        }
    }
}

@include generate-fruits(){
  background: $color;
};
```

> **result:** 
>   background gets black;
>
> **expected:**
>   background gets $fruit-color

It seems @content has been parsed before the Mixin action. **How can I force @content to keep the *mixin scope**?

Please, find out a simplified version of the problem [on codePen](http://codepen.io/gabrielagabriel/pen/WQGOdW).

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon to make a link to an "how to fix" answer, although I also asked **Why** this happened and, therefore, the answer to this question isn't completed. (1/3)

Comment: @cimmanon Reading closer the SASS_REFERENCE the !global definition determines > "Variables are only available within the level of nested selectors where they're defined. If they're defined outside of any nested selectors, they're available everywhere." but the SASS_CHANGELOG of 3.4+ [http://goo.gl/hRTGAI] show that this behaviour has changed: "All variable assignments not at the top level of the document are now local by default. If there’s a global variable with the same name, it won’t be overwritten unless the !global flag is used." (2/3)

Comment: @cimmanon IMHO, the SASS_CHANGELOG information is the **why** answer and could be interesting to let others know that. Could you consider to reopen this question?

Comment: @cimmanon Why *is* relevant! Stackoverflow is a platform to learn not just to get things "fixed".. If you don't know the "why", specially in this case, that the specification has changed the way of thinking about declaration you won't do it rationally. I would like to share what I've learned, that's why I'm asking to keep this question opened.

Comment: This question deserves better treatment; Comparing this one to the linked, this one is well explained. It's Author made more effort to explain his/her problem. I disagree with the __duplicate__ flag, the way the question is asked is different. Leading to the same answer is irrelevant.

Comment: I will answer that question if you want, and it won't be close to the linked self-answered answer's quality.

Comment: _"Leading to the same answer is irrelevant"_ -- incorrect. One of the reasons we even leave "duplicate" questions in the database is specifically because they are often asked in different ways, but lead to the same answer. This allows for the best answers to be situated in a single Q&A, while still enabling searchers to find the answer based on various possible ways to ask the question. It's completely understood that a person seeking the same answer may ask the question differently, and that's why SO's "duplicate" feature even works the way it does. If the answer's the same, it's a dupe.